# Lazy-Pipe-Evaluation when using "Select" to export CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, select, pipe, lazy-evaluation

**Intended Script Output:** I want to export a CSV file with certain columns from a Microsoft SharePoint list.

**Script-Outline:**
Firstly, I fetch the list items in `$items`:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
```

The columns for the output CSV file are defined in a hashmap `$h` (`$displayName => $internalName`).

Now I create a new *Hashtable* for each column and add it to `$selects`:

```
$selects = @()
foreach ($h in $mapping.GetEnumerator()) {
     $selects += @{ L = $h.Name; E = { $_[$h.Value] } }
}
```

Then I exoprt the CSV file:

```
$items | Select-Object $selects | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath
```

Now the problem:

In E I defined an expression which will be calculated only when I need it (lazily, so when the Select is executed).
When this happens, the reference to the `$h.Value` attribute has been altered, because `$h` is being looped over.
Therefore, when the expression is evaluated, `$h` points to the last object that has been looped over (so the last element of the hashmap). This is the case for every *select statement* being evaluated in the pipe.

I could fix this by saving the reference of `$h` (or to its Value) in another variable.
But then I need a hard-coded number of variables.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `{ $_[$h.Value] }` -> `{ $_[$h.Value] }.GetNewClosure()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), here the tested&working code example:

```
foreach ($h in $mapping.GetEnumerator()) {
     $selects += @{ L = $h.Name; E = { $_[$h.Value] }.GetNewClosure() }
}
```

We can freeze the reference to `$h`inside the loop by using closures, as explained [in this article](http://www.powertheshell.com/closure/).